# A PHP Error was encountered in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Help:

```
I have error:
```

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'periode'

Filename: models/k3m.php

Line Number: 32

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Warning

Message: Illegal string offset 'bulan'

Filename: models/k3m.php

Line Number: 33

Fatal error: Call to a member function row() on a non-object in C:\LaporBOS\htdocs\laporbos3\application\modules\laporan_k3\models\k3m.php on line 39

```
    function saldo_bank($param) {
    $periode = $param['periode'];
    $bulan = $param['bulan'];
    $bulan = $this->get_bulan2($periode,$bulan);
    $sql="SELECT IFNULL( SUM(IFNULL(jumlah_debet,0) ),0) - IFNULL( SUM(IFNULL(jumlah_kredit,0) ),0) AS saldo
            FROM buku_bank
            WHERE YEAR(tanggal) =".$this->session->userdata("tahun_anggaran")." 
            AND MONTH(tanggal) < $bulan";
    $data = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
    return $data->saldo;
}
```

Comment: `$param` param is a string but you treating it like an array.

Comment: `var_dump($param)` if type is array then The problem is you have no periode,and bulan key, if the type is `string` there you have it.

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you are calling row() before you have called result(), so change this

```
$data = $this->db->query($sql)->row();
```

to this

```
$data = $this->db->query($sql)->result()->row();
```

Comment: it's a bit hard to tell without the line numbers but I'd assume that even after you fix the other problem you will still need to add result() before row()

Answer (score 0):

The offset inside the array you passed is not available try to check that does the array
you pass has the offset you called and set it to variable.
check your $param array do write this at the top of your function

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($param); exit;
```

and than see

```
$periode = $param['periode'];
```

that "periode" or "bulan" is exist inside the array or not.